# Sequence increasing by percentage

Tags: r

Is it possible to create a seq in R with increasing values by percentage?

For example:

In need a sequence of values from 10500 to approximately 30000 increasing by 1 %

So the first value after 10500 have to be **10605**, the next one **10711.5** .....

Is this possible in R with the command `seq`? Ore maybe with another Function?

Something like:

```
seq(10500,30000,1%)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cumprod` is your friend:

```
cumprod(c(10500, rep(1.01,50)))
```

produces

```
 [1] 10500.00 10605.00 10711.05 10818.16 10926.34 11035.61 11145.96 11257.42 11370.00 11483.70
```

Comment: cumprod is my friend! Thanks a lot!

Comment: and obviously you can calculate how many times the `rep(1.01,xxx)` needs to be to get your max of 30000 using logs...

Comment: i.e. `10000 * (1.01)^n==30000` means `n=log(30000/10000)/log(1.01)`